# How can I make NSPopover detach programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover

I have a NSPopover that is draggable but I want to make it detach by clicking on a button. Like Bear Notes App.

Comment: Check my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031704/nspopover-to-start-in-a-detached-state/53589667#53589667